# Prove that there is a function $F$ from $[0, 1]$ to circle with radius 1, that $|Area(Im(F))-\pi| < \frac{1}{n}$ and $Im(F)$ is a regular polygon.

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry

I was doing the OMU test (https://www.olimpiada.ime.unicamp.br/), witch is already done (just to be clear), and came across the following question:

> Consider $C$ the circle with center in $(0, 0)$ and radius r = 1, that
> is:
> $$C = \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$$ Given any natural number $n> 0$, show that there is a function $F:[0, 1]\longrightarrow C$ so
> that:
>
> The image set of $F$, denoted by $Im(F)$ is a regular polygon with at
> least n sides and (I)
>
> $|Area(Im(f)) - \pi| < \frac{1}{n}$ is true (II)

Here is what I made:

If $Im(F)$ describes a poligon with p sides inscribed in $C$ and $p\longrightarrow \infty$, (II) is true, because the polygon area tends to be equal to circle area. So:
\begin{gather}
                |\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} Area(Im(f))-\pi| < \frac{1}{n} \\
                |(\pi*1)-\pi| < \frac{1}{n}\\
                0 < \frac{1}{n}\quad (true)
            \end{gather}
And (I) is true because:
$$[0, 1]\sim\mathbb{R}^2$$
and
$$\mathbb{R}^2\supseteq C \supseteq Im(f)$$
So there is a injection function from $[0, 1]$ to $Im(F)$ no matter $Im(F)$.

Have I made every thing right? And this was from the high school level so I supose there is another simplier way to solve, am I right? Could anyone help me?